# Using image to fill canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

This going to be a quite a long post. I'm creating a bounce game which require 3 files in a same folder in order for it to run (main.js , temp.js, index.html) as attached below. The game was ok and able to run until i decided to replace the canvas with image instead of painting it with color by editing the **paintCanvas()** function.

main.js (original file)

```js
// RequestAnimFrame: a browser API for getting smooth animations
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||  
    function( callback ){
      return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

window.cancelRequestAnimFrame = ( function() {
  return window.cancelAnimationFrame          ||
    window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame    ||
    window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame       ||
    window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame        ||
    clearTimeout
} )();


// Initialize canvas and required variables
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"), // Create canvas context
 W = window.innerWidth, // Window's width
    H = window.innerHeight, // Window's height
    //W = 1240, // Window's width
    //H = 900, // Window's height
    particles = [], // Array containing particles
    ball = {}, // Ball object
    //paddles = [2], // Array containing two paddles
 paddles = [1], // Array containing two paddles
    mouse = {}, // Mouse object to store it's current position
 temp_points =0,
 timeleft = 0,
    points = 0, // Varialbe to store points
 lives = 3,
 pause = true,
    fps = 60, // Max FPS (frames per second)
    particlesCount = 20, // Number of sparks when ball strikes the paddle
    flag = 0, // Flag variable which is changed on collision
    particlePos = {}, // Object to contain the position of collision 
    multipler = 1, // Varialbe to control the direction of sparks
    startBtn = {}, // Start button object
    restartBtn = {}, // Restart button object
    over = 0, // flag varialbe, cahnged when the game is over
    init, // variable to initialize animation
    paddleHit;
 
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
 if(!pause){
 timeleft += 1;
 }
}, 1000); 

// Add mousemove and mousedown events to the canvas
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", trackPosition, true);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", btnClick, true);

// Initialise the collision sound
collision = document.getElementById("collide");

// Set the canvas's height and width to full screen
canvas.width = W;
canvas.height = H;

// Function to paint canvas
function paintCanvas() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
  
}

// Function for creating paddles
function Paddle(pos) {
  // Height and width
  this.h = 5;
  this.w = 150;
  
  // Paddle's position
  this.x = W/2 - this.w/2;
  this.y = (pos == "top") ? 0 : H - this.h;
  
}

// Push two new paddles into the paddles[] array
//paddles.push(new Paddle("bottom"));
//paddles.push(new Paddle("top"));
paddles.push(new Paddle("top"));

// Ball object
ball = {
  x: 500,
  y: 10, 
  r: 5,
  c: "white",
  vx: 4,
  vy: 8,
  
  // Function for drawing ball on canvas
  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.c;
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fill();
  }
};


// Start Button object
startBtn = {
  w: 100,
  h: 50,
  x: W/2 - 50,
  y: H/2 - 25,
  
  draw: function() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.lineWidth = "2";
    ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    
    ctx.font = "18px Arial, sans-serif";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillStlye = "white";
    ctx.fillText("Start", W/2, H/2 );
  }
  
};

// Restart Button object
restartBtn = {
  w: 100,
  h: 50,
  x: W/2 - 50,
  y: H/2 - 50,
  
  draw: function() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.lineWidth = "2";
    ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    
    ctx.font = "18px Arial, sans-serif";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillStlye = "white";
    ctx.fillText("Restart", W/2, H/2 - 25 );
  }
};

// Function for creating particles object
function createParticles(x, y, m) {
  this.x = x || 0;
  this.y = y || 0;
  
  this.radius = 1.2;
  
  this.vx = -1.5 + Math.random()*3;
  this.vy = m * Math.random()*1.5;
}

// Draw everything on canvas
function draw() {
  paintCanvas();
  for(var i = 0; i < paddles.length; i++) {
    p = paddles[i];
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(p.x, p.y, p.w, p.h);
  }
  
  ball.draw();
  update();
}

// Track the position of mouse cursor
function trackPosition(e) {
  mouse.x = e.pageX;
  mouse.y = e.pageY;
}

// Function to update positions, score and everything.
// Basically, the main game logic is defined here
function update() {
  
  // Update scores
  updateScore(); 
  
  // Update lives
  updateLives();
  
  // Update timer
  timeLeft();
  // Move the paddles on mouse move
  if(mouse.x && mouse.y) {
    for(var i = 1; i < paddles.length; i++) {
      p = paddles[i];
      p.x = mouse.x - p.w/2;
    }   
  }
  
  
  // Move the ball
  ball.x += ball.vx;
  ball.y += ball.vy;
  
  // Collision with paddles
  p1 = paddles[1];
  
  // If the ball strikes with paddles,
  // invert the y-velocity vector of ball,
  // increment the points, play the collision sound,
  // save collision's position so that sparks can be
  // emitted from that position, set the flag variable,
  // and change the multiplier
  if(collides(ball, p1)) {
    collideAction(ball, p1);
  }
  
  
  else {
    // Collide with walls, If the ball hits the top/bottom,
    // walls, run gameOver() function
    
 if(ball.y < 0) {
      ball.y = ball.r;
      gameOver();
 }
    
    // If ball strikes the vertical walls, invert the 
    // x-velocity vector of ball
    if(ball.x + ball.r > W) {
      ball.vx = -ball.vx;
      ball.x = W - ball.r;
    }
    
    else if(ball.x -ball.r < 0) {
      ball.vx = -ball.vx;
      ball.x = ball.r;
    }
 
 else if(ball.y + ball.r > H) {
  ball.vy = -ball.vy;
        ball.y = H - ball.r;
 }
  }
  
  // If flag is set, push the particles
  if(flag == 1) { 
    for(var k = 0; k < particlesCount; k++) {
      particles.push(new createParticles(particlePos.x, particlePos.y, multiplier));
    }
  } 
  
  // Emit particles/sparks
  emitParticles();
  
  // reset flag
  flag = 0;
}

//Function to check collision between ball and one of
//the paddles
function collides(b, p) {
  if(b.x + ball.r >= p.x && b.x - ball.r <=p.x + p.w) {
    if(b.y >= (p.y - p.h) && p.y > 0){
      paddleHit = 1;
      return true;
    }
    
    else if(b.y <= p.h && p.y == 0) {
      paddleHit = 2;
      return true;
    }
    
    else return false;
  }
}

//Do this when collides == true
function collideAction(ball, p) {
  ball.vy = -ball.vy;
  
  if(paddleHit == 1) {
    ball.y = p.y - p.h;
    particlePos.y = ball.y + ball.r;
    multiplier = -1;  
  }
  
  points++;
  
  if(collision) {
    if(points > 0) 
      collision.pause();
    
    collision.currentTime = 0;
    collision.play();
  }
  
  particlePos.x = ball.x;
  flag = 1;
}

// Function for emitting particles
function emitParticles() { 
  for(var j = 0; j < particles.length; j++) {
    par = particles[j];
    
    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    if (par.radius > 0) {
      ctx.arc(par.x, par.y, par.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    }
    ctx.fill();  
    
    par.x += par.vx; 
    par.y += par.vy; 
    
    // Reduce radius so that the particles die after a few seconds
    par.radius -= 0.05; 
    
  } 
}

// Function for updating score
function updateScore() {
  ctx.fillStlye = "white";
  ctx.font = "16px Arial, sans-serif";
  ctx.textAlign = "left";
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.fillText("Score: " + points, 20, 20 );
}

// Function for updating Lives
function updateLives() {
  ctx.fillStlye = "white";
  ctx.font = "16px Arial, sans-serif";
  ctx.textAlign = "right";
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.fillText("Lives: " + lives, 900, 20 );
}

// Function for timer
function timeLeft() {
  ctx.fillStlye = "white";
  ctx.font = "16px Arial, sans-serif";
  ctx.textAlign = "right";
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.fillText("Timer: " + timeleft+ " seconds", 700, 20 );
}


// Function to run when the game overs
function gameOver() {
  ctx.fillStlye = "white";
  ctx.font = "20px Arial, sans-serif";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  if(lives == 1){
 ctx.fillText("Game Over - You scored "+points+" points! within "+timeleft+" seconds", W/2, H/2 + 25 );
 pause = true;
   
  }
  else{
 ctx.fillText("You have "+(lives-1)+" lives left!!", W/2, H/2 + 25 );
 pause = true;
  }
  
  
  // Stop the Animation
  cancelRequestAnimFrame(init);
  
  // Set the over flag
  over = 1;
  temp_points = points;
  lives--;
  // Show the restart button
  restartBtn.draw();
}

// Function for running the whole animation
function animloop() {
  init = requestAnimFrame(animloop);
  draw();
}

// Function to execute at startup
function startScreen() {
 
  draw();
  startBtn.draw();
}

// On button click (Restart and start)
function btnClick(e) {
  
  pause = false;
  // Variables for storing mouse position on click
  var mx = e.pageX,
      my = e.pageY;
  
  // Click start button
  if(mx >= startBtn.x && mx <= startBtn.x + startBtn.w) {
    animloop();
    
    // Delete the start button after clicking it
    startBtn = {};
  }
  
  // If the game is over, and the restart button is clicked
  if(over == 1) {
   if(lives == 0){
    if(mx >= restartBtn.x && mx <= restartBtn.x + restartBtn.w) {
   ball.x = 500;
   ball.y = 10;
   points = 0;
   ball.vx = 4;
   ball.vy = 8;
   animloop();
   lives = 3;
   over = 0;
   timeleft = 0;
   pause = false;
   
   }
   }
   else{
    if(mx >= restartBtn.x && mx <= restartBtn.x + restartBtn.w) {
   ball.x = 500;
   ball.y = 10;
   points = temp_points;
   ball.vx = 4;
   ball.vy = 8;
   animloop();
   over = 0;
   pause = false;
   
   }
   }
    
  }
}

// Show the start screen
startScreen();
```

**temp.js (original file)**

```js
var timeleft = 10;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById("progressBar").value = 10 - timeleft;
  timeleft -= 1;
  if(timeleft <= 0)
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
}, 1000);
```

**index.html (original file)**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML5 Ping-Pong Game</title>
    <style>
      body {padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <audio preload="true" id="collide">
      <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26141789/canvas/pingpong/Metal%20Cling%20-%20Hit.mp3" />
      <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26141789/canvas/pingpong/Metal%20Cling%20-%20Hit.wav" />
    </audio>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code I'm trying to edit in **paintCanvas()** function inside the main.js file:

```js
function paintCanvas() {
  
 var blueprint_background = new Image();
 blueprint_background.src = 'C:/Users/EIGHT/Desktop/worldskill/download.jpg'; 
 blueprint_background.onload = function(){
    var pattern = ctx.createPattern(this, "repeat");
    ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
 //ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
    ctx.fill();
 };
}
```

The screenshot for the bounce game using the original code

[original paintCanvas() code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twu2O.png)

The screenshot after i tried editing the paintCanvas() function by inserting images instead of using color fillstyle.

[editted paintCanvas() code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzHi5.png)

After editing the paintCanvas() function the code below, i found out the picture are overlapping all the text and the ball.  Hope someone could help on this. Thanks

Comment: How are you running this? Do you have more files? Also it's not really clear which part your having a problem with. Could you specify where your problem is?

Comment: Hi jacob, i just edit my post with other attached file and also the problem i facing. thanks